# Multiprocessing array .get_lock works on one computer but not another

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am working a somewhat extensive python program that uses multiprocessing.  Because I wanted the user to see some progress on the console when running the program, I read about using a shared counter on stackoverflow and after a while of playing around with my code, I got it to work.  As I said it's too much code to post here, but the gist is that I instantiate a multiprocessing array after the `name==main line`,

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    total_progress_counter = Array('i',[0,0])
```

and then during the main portion of code I pass this array to a function in other module:

```
some_name.plot(<other variables>,
               total_progress_counter=total_progress_counter)
```

Then within that other function, I used the `.get_lock` method that I found described here on stackoverflow:

```
with total_progress_counter.get_lock():
    total_progress_counter[0] += self.total_panels_to_plot
```

I also update the other component, `total_progress_counter[1]`, in the same function.  This works fine for me on my work machine, where I wrote the code, and that machine has a Centos operating system.

But, when I run it on my personal MacBook it gives the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./program.py", line 775, in <module>
    program.run()
  File "./program.py", line 177, in run
    cases_plotted = pool.map(self.__plot__, all_cases)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_lock'
```

I have python3 version 3.8.3 on my personal machine and python3 version 3.7.4 on my work machine.  Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting different behavior on these two environments?  I'd be grateful, as this is meant to be software others might use on different machines.

Comment: A `multiprocessing.Array` certainly has a get_lock() method on my MBP running 3.8.  Can you print out the value of `total_progress_counter` before calling get_lock()?  The error message makes me think its value is something else.

Comment: Actually, I was able to get it to work on both my home and work computers after I realized I had not initialized the Pool statement (i.e. `Pool(initializer=<something>,initargs=(<something>,))`.  I'm not sure why the code worked without this on my work machine, but hopefully this is a general fix.

Comment: Just for my own general knowledge.  Did you do the experiment of printing out `total_progress_counter` having left out the initialization?  It's good to know how things fail.

Comment: Yes I did try that, and it was printing `[0,0]`, as it was originally initialized (before I corrected the instantiation of `Pool`.